# Why is a tableView with mutableArray so hard to implement?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've literally been trying to get a tableView implemented correctly for over 20 hours nows. I've asked a few questions to stack overflow and looked at dozens of other questions as well as questions in forums with similar problems. The closest I have gotten is a running program with an empty tableView. I am very frustrated with objective c.

Can someone post an example of a single table view loaded with a mutable array with data added from a text view and a button? Here is one variant of my useless code...it's not running with the following error:

```
2013-06-10 11:42:05.939 WIDMIR Sign-In[32878:11303] *** Terminating app due to 
uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x7517c00> 
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for 
the key add.'
*** First throw call stack: (0x1c93012 0x10d0e7e 0x1d1bfb1 0xb7ce41 0xafe5f8 0xafe0e7
0xb28b58 0x232019 0x10e4663 0x1c8e45a 0x230b1c 0xf57e7 0xf5dc8 0xf5ff8 0xf6232 0x453d5  
0x4576f 0x45905 0x4e917 0x231b 0x12157 0x12747 0x1394b 0x24cb5 0x25beb 0x17698 0x1beedf9 
0x1beead0 0x1c08bf5 0x1c08962 0x1c39bb6 0x1c38f44 0x1c38e1b 0x1317a 0x14ffc 0x1f5d 0x1e85)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception (lldb)
```

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    UITableView *tableView;
}

- (IBAction)add:(id)sender;


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *currentNames;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize name;

@synthesize currentNames;

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.currentNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView = tv;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [currentNames count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [currentNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    [currentNames addObject:[name text]];
    [tableView reloadData];

    name.text=@"";
}
@end
```

Comment: I dont think, that calling `[tableView reloadData]`in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and other delegate/datasource methods is a good idea. should result in infinite loops. And that is also the answer to you question: You didn't study the documentation.  at least not carefully enough. programming without understanding has to be hard.

Comment: Don't call reloadData inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: You should create a master-detail template project in Xcode. It provides all the code you need to have a functional example of what you ask.

Comment: And the exception you're having may come from broken outlets in your storyboard. Check the connections inspector on the objects of your storyboard for little warning icons.

Comment: viking & verbumdei - I added that in frustration, forgot to remove it. Nonetheless that does nothing to fix my code and I have read the documentation...

Comment: @verbumdei is right. Calling reloadData will end up in an endless loop, given that it was called at all. Why don't you just use one of the many table view tutorials?

Comment: delegate/datasource not set or not fully implemented, outlet not connected, un-initialized array: it comes always down to one of these

Comment: I suspect there is invalid method connection in the storyboard for your IBAction add method.

Comment: the tableview is created by code, but it's delegate and datasource is never set. but this doesnt explain the error message. in what line is it thrown?

Comment: and the tableview is never added to the view hierarchy

Comment: I've fixed the error and I have the empty table view now. I have my tableView connected to the file's owner datasource and delegate. I believe it has to do with my implementation of my mutable array as the  tableview is populated correctly with other sample data.

Comment: viking - I think you're right with the outlet not connected as I have the warning: "local declaration of tableView hides instance variable" inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. How do I fix that?

Comment: verbumdei - I don't believe the add is incorrect as I have added a test label to change with the text to be added to the array, and it updates correctly when I hit the add button.

Comment: It finally worked! Refer to Hermann's answer as to why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set '`self`' as the delegate or datasource of your table view. Therefor `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `numberOfRowsInSection:` should not be called. Did you set breakpoints or so to find out wether they have been called at all?

The error message suggests that you try to assign a value to a property "add". Can you localize where the exception is thrown? Did you try adding an "All Exceptions" breakpoint? If not then do so and we go from there.

Comment: Do not name your instance `tableView`, because as you can see, it's by this name that the delegates methods get the instance of the `UITableView`. Rename it into `_tableView` or something else but not `tableview`.

Comment: For example with the method : `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`. I hope you understand what I try to explain :/

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I am glad it worked eventually.